# Iasyncresult - why it is not just object, why it is interface?

Tags: c#, iasyncresult

I just cannot figure out what why IAsyncResult is an interface instead of simple object. As I remember correctly, interface contains only method names without implementation so I canot see how it is used here as I do not derive any class of it nor override its methods? I am just confused..Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn’t BeginInvoke return reference of type AsyncResult?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352161/why-doesnt-begininvoke-return-reference-of-type-asyncresult)

Answer (score 2):

If it were just an object, it could be anything - and you could *not* rely on certain properties and/or methods being present, like you can when you know you'll get an object that implements the interface `IAsyncResult`.

Since the object you're getting back must be implementing the interface in question, you can rely on the fact that the properties `AsyncState`, `AsyncWaitHandle`, `CompletedSynchronously` and `IsCompleted` will be present.

If you had just an object and you got back an `int` - how would you get those properties you need??

Answer (score 1):

Like this, the result can be any type of object, which implements the IAsyncResult interface.

You're right that an interface only contains methods/properties without implementation.
In this case, it is garanteed that the AsyncResult object contains the methods which are needed by the 'Async-framework'.

The IAsyncResult contains four properties:

- AsyncState (Object)
- AsyncWaitHandle (WaitHandle)
- CompletedSynchronously (Boolean)
- IsCompleted (Boolean)

Those properties are simply required when working with Async methods. If it would be an object, you would be less flexible I think.

Answer (score 1):

Because an "ASyncResult" in itself is nothing concrete.

Because C# only allows single inheretance, by making it an interface you can implement it on any object type you choose.

For example, if I my method returns type Foo, I can create an async return type for my app simply by creating a subclass saying

```
FooAsync : Foo, IAsyncResult
```

And simply cast it as opposed writing code to extract values.